# Is there a way in R to count the number of occurrences of a event between two different events?

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I'm analyzing the management in rotation forestry where the forest is planted, then as it grows it is thinned a few times by harvesting some trees and then, in the end, all trees are cut down.

Here's an example of what my data could look like:

```
year <- rep(seq(1,10, 1),3)
stand <- c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,10))
treatment <- c("planting", "none", "thinning", "none", "thinning", "none", "none", "felling", "planting", "none",
               "none", "planting", "thinning", "thinning", "thinning","none", "felling", "planting", "thinning", "none",
               "planting", "none", "thinning","none", "felling", "planting", "thinning","none", "thinning", "felling")
data <- data.frame(year,stand,treatment)
```

The three stands have very different rotations.

- Stand 1 is planted in the first year, then is thinned twice and felled in year 8 and planted again in year 9. There is one complete rotation and 2 fellings per rotation
- Stand 2 is planted in year 2, thinned 3 times and then felled in year 7. After this, a new forest is planted and thinned once but the rotation is not completed. So there is one rotation and there are 3 thinnings per rotation.
- Stand 3 has two rotations with one thinning in rotation 1 and two in rotation 2. The result should show that there are, on average, 1.5 thinnings per rotation.

I have thousands of stands with all sorts of rotation schedules, so it is impossible to count this manually for me. How can I write a script to calculate the number of thinnings per complete rotation (the years in between planting and felling)?

In the end, I would like to have a table with the stand number and number of thinnings per complete rotation. All incomplete rotations should be discarded.

Comment: Please include a) what you expect the result from the example data to look like. b) motivate helpers by providing information on what you already tried to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every `stand` we can keep everything between first `'planting'` and last `'felling'` since we want to consider only complete rotation. We then calculate number of `'thinning'` and divide it by number of `'planting'` which happened in that `stand` to get thinning per rotation.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(stand) %>%
  filter(between(row_number(), min(which(treatment == 'planting')), 
                               max(which(treatment == 'felling')))) %>%
  summarise(thin_per_rotation = sum(treatment == 'thinning')/
                                sum(treatment == 'planting'))


#  stand thin_per_rotation
#  <dbl>             <dbl>
#1     1               2  
#2     2               3  
#3     3               1.5
```

Comment: Then all rows before the first planting should be deleted as well.
data %>%
  group_by(stand) %>%
  slice(min(which(treatment == 'felling')):length()) %>%
  slice(1:max(which(treatment == 'felling'))) %>%
  summarise(thin_per_rotation = sum(treatment == 'thinning')/
                                sum(treatment == 'planting'))

Comment: @triroba Can you have `'thinning'` before first `'planting'`? I have updated the answer though.